# Traceback error when using loop

Tags: python, cmd

The below code is written in python.

```
import subprocess as sp

def user_input():
    sp.call('cls',shell=True)
    print('[1]: ASCII to Binary')
    print('[2]: Binary to ASCII')
    valid_answer()

def valid_answer():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input('Please type 1 or 2: '))
            sp.call('cls',shell=True)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid input...')
            sp.call('pause',shell=True)
            user_input()

    while True:
        if user_input < 0:
            print('Input must be 1 or 2.')
            sp.call('pause',shell=True)
            user_input()
        elif user_input > 2:
            print('Input must be 1 or 2.')
            sp.call('pause',shell=True)
            user_input()
        else:
            break
    if user_input == (1):
        print('Good.')
        exit
    elif user_input == (2):
        print('Good.')
        exit

user_input()
```

Whenever I run the file in the CMD Shell, it works fine, until I get to this part of the code:

```
while True:
    if user_input < 0:
        print('Input must be 1 or 2.')
        sp.call('pause',shell=True)
        user_input()
    elif user_input > 2:
        print('Input must be 1 or 2.')
        sp.call('pause',shell=True)
        user_input()
    else:
        break
```

If user_input doesn't return as 1 or 2, I get this error:

[image: Error Image]

I can't exactly figure out what is wrong with my code, and I don't understand any of the errors thrown by the CMD Shell. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
user_input = int(input('Please type 1 or 2: '))
```

At this point, you set `user_input` to a number, and then later on you are trying to call that number with `user_input()`, its the same as doing this:

```
>>> user_input = 1
>>> user_input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: So, what I need to do is either change `def user_input():` to something other than `user_input`, or change the variable?

Comment: Yep, my recommendation is to change the variable; and while you are at it, `if user_input == (1):` you don't need `()` around the `1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `ValueError` will take care of that.

Comment: Now that I fixed that problem, what happens now is I just loop back to `user_input()` instead of closing the shell.